# Query Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query Firebase database using the below method to obtain all the userId's, whose registration status is `approved`, but I am unable to.

Could someone please suggest/guide me how I could do this ?

```
var registeredUsersRef = firebaseDB.ref("users/registered/");
registeredUsersRef.orderByChild("registrationData").orderByChild("registrationStatus").equalTo("approved").once('value', snapshot => {

}
```

Below is my Sample Data Structure

```
{
  "users" : 
      {
        "registered" : 
          {
            "userId1" : {
                "registrationData" : {
                  "registrationStatus" : "approved",
                  "experience" : "10 yrs",
                  "firstName" : "Peter",
                }
            },
            "userId2" : {
                "registrationData" : {
                  "registrationStatus" : "notApproved",
                  "experience" : "7 yrs",
                  "firstName" : "Simon",
                }
            },
            "userId3" : {
                "registrationData" : {
                  "registrationStatus" : "awaitingApproval",
                  "experience" : "5 yrs",
                  "firstName" : "Bob",
                }
            }
          }
      }
}
    }
```

Comment: I think you are missing "userId1" (child of registered)

Comment: I do not have the `userId` value.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase